# SharePoint 2013 Calendar Time Filter

Tags: list-view, filter, sharepoint-calendar, sharepiont

I am trying to create a view which only shows the event that are current. I know there is 'current event' view available but it doesn't filter based on the 'time' so if an event finished at 5pm and now it 5:01pm it shouldn't show me this event. [Today] also doesn't work with time.  Is it possible OOTB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve by adding IncludeTimeValue="True" to two calculated columns in the View.

For the complete walk-through please see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/16aef6a5-9159-4494-857d-a27149eeb015/sharepoint-2013-calender-to-filter-on-time?forum=sharepointgeneral